# Unable to bind function on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a simple shopping cart with javascript, and what would a shopping cart without a button to remove an item be?

The cart is created on-the-fly with javascript, so the elements won't exist on page load. However, this shouldn't be a problem with this?

```
$(".removeFromCart").on("click",function(e){
    alert("GO AWAY PLEASE..");
    var tuoteID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    deleteFromCart(tuoteID);
});
```

The element (created on the fly) simply looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="removeFromCart" data-id="2">×</a>
```

But it won't trigger. If I replace `.replaceFromCart` with, for example, `p`, it will trigger every time I click on a paragraph.

This isn't the first time I'm having problems with `.on()` and it always takes half of my hair to solve, so maybe someone with more experience could point me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This question has been asked more times than i can remember.

Comment: @PatsyIssa probably, but english isn't my native language, so it isn't that easy to always find the right words to find the right results. I did find a couple of solutions with `.live()` or similar.

Comment: As you write the question SO shows you suggestions about similar questions, keep an eye out for it ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need event delegation, using other version of the jQuery [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) function. You have to give the static parent that is present the time the binding code is executed or you can delegate to `body` or `document`.

```
$(document).on("click",".removeFromCart", function(e){
    alert("GO AWAY PLEASE..");
    var tuoteID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    deleteFromCart(tuoteID);
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thank you! Where I would be without stackoverflow...

Comment: @Christian On jQuery Docs

Comment: @Mr.Alien On jQuery docs I see a ****load of text, filled with words that I won't encounter so often. It has a lot of examples but it's rare to find an example I can directly use ;)